# Using ranges for raster colour map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, color

I have a raster layer in GeoTIFF format, with continuous data values between -1 and +1. For the colour map, I would like...

- > 0 to be green
- = 0 to be grey
- <0 to -0.25 to be pink
- <-0.25 to -0.50 to be dark pink

...etc to 1. Is this possible with QGIS? I tried putting ranges in the colour map box, but it didn't work.

Comment: > *but it didn't work.*

is not helpful. What did not work exactly?

Comment: Putting ranges in the colourmap Value box, e.g. using relational operators like in the example above. It reverts to 0 when the dialogue box is closed and reopened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work for me on a -1.0 - 1.0 NDVI raster

- Double click on the raster layer in QGIS table of contents/layer
  list
- Click "Style" tab (1st tab on the left)
- Select "Render as" -> "single band gray" and "Single band properties" -> "Color map" -> "Colormap"
- Click "Colormap" tab (2nd tab from the left)
- Click "Add entry" and add the following entries:

  - -0.4999999 (< -0.5)
  - -0.2499999 (>-0.5 <-0.25)
  - -0.0000001 (> -0.25 <0.0)
  - 0.000000   (=0)
  - 1          ( >0 <=1)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to classify your raster using GRASS r.reclass from the Sextante toolbox. You'll need a 'rules' text file to do this, there are some examples [here](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass54/manual/html/r.reclass.html). Example 2 is probably something like you'd need (with a bit of editing, of course). r.reclass groups raster values into classes following the rules set in the 'rules' text file.

Comment: I could reclass in QGIS too, using the Raster Calculator. I was hoping to do it from the Styles/Colormap dialogue, though perhaps it will be easier to reclass into a new raster.

Comment: If you use r.reclass you could then (if you wish) unleash the raster polygonzer on the raster to make a vector polygon shapefile for colour styling. Just a thought. N.